# I am having problems installing pyperclip

Tags: python, installation, pyperclip

i am currently new to python. I am following the book Automate python
I am having problem installing pyperclip
it keeps saying access denied 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOY8q.png)

as the picture shows i follow the right steps but i keep getting denied

Note: I am on the admin account when trying to install pyperclip from command prompt. I am using windows 7.

How do i overcome this issue?
Is there any alternative way to install pyperclip?

Please help thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should not install python to `C:\Program Files` because it is not writable by normal user. If it's possible, do consider installing python at a more permissive location such as `C:\Python35` or anywhere else except `C:\Program Files` and `C:\Program Files (x86)`

**quickfix**: open `Command Prompt (Admin)` by pressing `Alt + x + a`. Then use `pip install pyperclip` to install the package.