# Installing PIP Modules

Tags: python, pip, pyperclip

I am having trouble installing any PIP module.

Steps/Precautions I have taken:

1. I uninstalled Python and downloaded the most recent Python 3.6.2.
2. PIP seems to be installed already C:\Users\Danc2>C:\Users\Danc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\scripts\pip3.6 (also included are files: pip, pip3).
3. `pip install pyperclip` returns

   > 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
4. In using many different forums and typing commands into CMD I come up with results like: "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file."
5. When trying to refer to my folder location: "C:\Users\Danc2>C:\Users\Danc2>C:\Users\Danc2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\scripts
   Access is denied."

Sorry for the common question, but I just cannot figure it out for my individual problem. I appreciate any kind effort to help.

Daniel.

Comment: Try using:
>>>py -m pip install <package>

Comment: Looking at the install location for Python, definitely you are going to get `Access Denied` messages. Uninstall and install either in the default location, `C:\Python36` or in a location that does not admin privileges to access. That is the reason even when you run the command, the command is not recognised. unless you want to run `cmd` as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, guys. Between your answers and another post, I figured it out.

Apparently, my installation location (and program files) for Python was preventing me from installing pyperclip. I bypassed this issue by running CMD as an administrator (see [Stack Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422169/i-am-having-problems-installing-pyperclip) .I will still reinstall elsewhere.

Cheers,

Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restart your computer. If that doesn't work, go to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables.

In the system variables you should go to Path and add the folder containing the pip.exe to your path.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python installation works at all with the command line, then replacing `pip` with `python -m pip` in the command line is likely to fix the issue for you.